# SwiftUI – Xcode not building when using the index variable of a ForEach loop

Tags: swift, if-statement, swiftui

I have a `ForEach` loop inside a `TabView`. Whenever I try to build the project using the `index` (for lack of a better word, here: *slide*) variable in a condition, it stalls and is not building; it's not showing any errors. If I'm using it interpolated, it works/builds.

```
TabView {
  ForEach(1...3, id: \.self) { slide in
    HStack {

       if slide == 1 {
         Text("Do something if slide is 1st slide") // doesn't work
       }
     
       Text("Test \(slide)") // works
    }
    .tag(slide)
  }
}
```

Thanks for any tips!

**Edit:** Deleted case 2)
**Edit:** Added `Tabview`

Comment: Case 1) built fine here, case 2) should not be built as incorrect use - `Text` expects strings, so case 2 should be used as case 3) `Text("\(slide)")`

Comment: Works (mostly) for me in a playground, there must be something else going on in your project or Xcode installation. `Text(slide)` does not work because `Text` does not have an `init` that takes an `Int`. Also, `if` does not require parentheses around the condition.

Comment: @Gereon Ah, thanks for the info about the parentheses! Weird, yeah maybe it's something with the installation.

Comment: @Asperi Thanks, I deleted case 2)

Comment: When I remove the `tag(slide)` from the `TabView` `HStack`-slide it works. Don't know why though :/

Comment: @ToE It works for me! maybe something else causing the build issue.

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger Yeah, using the variable in the `.tag` was the issue. Removing it made it work. I'm too new to swift to understand why though. Maybe because `.tag` needs a `String` or another form of the "slide" variable.

Comment: Your code works as edited with the addition of a `.tabViewStyle(.page)` to make it navigate the tabs. Having the variable as a tag is fine. Try cleaning your build folder and deleting your derived data folder.